# emacs - paste text from clipboard without formatting

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, clipboard, macos, indentation

I am using Emacs 24 for macOS. I'm having some problem with pasting code from clipboard to Emacs. The code that I usually select already is nicely formatted (with tab, indent, ...).

However, when I paste it to Emacs, this redoes the formatting, so it is extremely slow for thousands of lines of code.

Is there a way to paste from clipboard without formatting?

Answer (score 5):

try: `c-toggle-syntactic-indentation` before your paste.

Comment: Alt-X `c-toggle-syntactic-indentation`

This only works for one paste.

Answer (score 1):

I use `clipboard-yank` and `clipboard-kill-region` to interact with the clipboard from inside `emacs`. I never had indentation problems.

Does the problem persist when you use these two functions?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists for me: emacs 24, OSX 10.10.